# MATLAB: Check if a row exists or not in an array and if not add it to the end of another array

Tags: arrays, algorithm, matlab, rows, fifo

I have two arrays Q and Q2, double arrays 5520x4, both of them are exactly the same at the beginning. Schematically Q is like this:

[image]

The rows in Q represent mathematic relations between variables, for example the first row in the Q means:
x0-x3 = 84 and so on.
Also, Q2 is pretty much identical, like this:

[image]

During my algorithm, Q has to do some deletions of rows, while Q2 is made to maintain all the rows.

The rows are just mathematic relations that need to be checked from another function, which i am using later in the program. 
So, what i really would like to know is how could i check if a specific row exists or not in Q2 after some row deletions from array Q? If it does not exist, it must be added at the end of Q (fifo policy queue). Otherwise, if it does exist, we have nothing to do, the algorithm goes on until the Q is empty.

Could someone please suggest a reliable and efficient way to achieve this check?

I used to have both Q and Q2 as cell arrays, but cellfun was way too slow for more complicated problems.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Thanks a lot for your time,

NickH

Comment: check out ismember for input 'rows', see here http://uk.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/245042

Comment: `ismember` should sort you out, but you should add some sample input **and** output data. Use like only 3 rows for `Q` so it's easy to see. Also instead of a screenshot, type it out so we can just copy it straight in to Matlab